# Will Facebook Share Button Be Considered Spam?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

This is just a quick question. If I put a Facebook share button in my website and the users are encouraged to share a lot to get points and such, will Facebook be able to block / consider my site as spam if the users are the one who are willing to share (post to their wall) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not considered as spam. We used to use publish_stream in the past and posting through graph api and that caused us lots of troubles because of the spam filter tagging our apps as spam apps. We never had that issue with facebook share button.

Comment: Yeah, we've had some issues with publish_stream too, that's why we're planning to use the share button as a workaround. Sure we can limit so the user can only share once per day or something like that, but it kinda defeats the purpose I think.

Comment: I think the general idea is that publish_steam is possible behind the scenes and that's the reason it's so restrictive. While the share functionality explicitly requires user interaction.